# How to use [Index] attribute in Entity Framework 6.1.1 with Code First

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm using Entity Framework 6.1.1 and Code first.   EF 6.1 should have added support for the [Index attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591583.aspx#Index), but neither the editor auto-completion or compiler accept the [Index] attribute such as:

```
[Index]
public DateTime TimeOfSale { get; set; }
```

All project references point to the DLLs for EF 6.1.1.

I'm also running SQL Server Compact Edition 4.0.

How to enable the use of the new [Index] attribute?

Comment: Do you have the relevant `using` statement in the file with this code in?

Comment: Yes - I have using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations; , and the [Key] attribute is accepted.

Comment: Which version of .NET Framework your projects are using?

Comment: .NET 4.0 full profile

Comment: I still need to support XP and Server 2003 clients.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

While the `KeyAttribute` is in the `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations` namespace, the `IndexAttribute` class is in the `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema` namespace. You are likely missing the following `using` statement:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
```

Comment: I have the same problem. Adding Schema with a using statement didn't help.

Comment: Worked perfectly for me. But I had already upgraded my package to 6.1.2. Note that the Visual Studio 2013 Community Edition uses 6.0.something out of the <virtual> box and you have to upgrade to the new version of EF before the Using will help.

Comment: @MeetingAttender you may be on an older version of .Net. Try using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

Answer (score 4):

Note if you are working in ASP.NET Core as of this writing the Index attribute is not supported.  An alternative is nicely outlined in this SO post though: [Asp.net Core Entity Framework cannot find IndexAttribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38531092/asp-net-core-entity-framework-cannot-find-indexattribute)